# how to delete a row or line in a text file using java

Tags: java, delete-row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Find a line in a file and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove)

```
ChavezJan2012   SLC   1.25
ChavezFeb2012   SLC   0.25
ChavezMar2012   SLC   1.25
```

I have this data written in a text file using java and i wanted to delete one row out of the 3 rows in my file.  I'm still trying my best to find a solution as of the moment using an arrayList.

```
ChavezJan2012   SLC   1.25
ChavezMar2012   SLC   1.25
```

Desired result after the deletion. Please help, thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do is create a temporary file. Write all the text in that file except the line to be omitted. And rename that temporary file to old file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop with indexing i+3 for example:

```
for (int i=0 i < arraylist.size(); i+3){

writeToFile.arraylist.get(i);
writeToFile.arraylist.get(i+2);

}
```