# Get id number and if found, Delete it

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Find a line in a file and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove)

I have a code that Get id number and search for its records, if exist, display it.

I want if found, delete it record.
One solution for delete a line( a user record) is create another file and copy all lines without found record.
can anyone tell me another solution? (Simple solution)

my BookRecords.txt file is this:

```
Name        Date        Number

one   2002   22
two   2003   33
three   2004   44
four   2005   55
```

my Code to find :

```
String bookid=jTextField2.getText();
File f=new File("C:\\BookRecords.txt");
try{
    FileReader Bfr=new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader Bbr=new BufferedReader(Bfr);
    String bs;
    while( (bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
    String[] Ust=bs.split("   ");
    String Bname=Ust[0];
    String Bdate=Ust[1];
    String id = Ust[2];
    if (id.equals(bookid.trim()) 
    jLabel1.setText("Book Found,    "+ Bname + "    " + Bdate);
    break;
        }
      }
    }
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

please help to delete a Line(a Record)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on a single text file is - uhm - a bit strange. But I would recommend, that you create a new text file (output):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
```

Only write the lines that *don't* match the book's ID.

```
while (...) {
    ...
    if (!id.equals(bookid.trim())) {
        out.println(bs);
    }
}
out.close();
```

Later you can rename the file, if you like.

Comment: Thank you, please write complete code, What is while condition?

Comment: And where should place this statement?

Comment: `while` is the same you already have. Just replace your `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

replace the entire line in the text file with a backspace character when found

> \b

Comment: Please Write complete code and Explain!

Comment: Hi.. was working on the code. Realised that Java does not understand the '\b' (backspace) character. This solution won't work. You can check the solution pointed out by Lenymm