# Java remove complete line from file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Find a line in a file and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove)

I am trying to remove a complete line from a text file, and have managed to remove the line if there is only one single unbroken line of text without spaces. If i have a space delimiter between strings it fails to remove anything.
Code as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class removebooks {
     // construct temporary file
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException {
    String title;

     Scanner titlerem= new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter Title to remove from file");
     title = titlerem.next ();

     // construct temporary file
     File inputFile = new File("books.txt");
     File tempFile = new File(inputFile + "temp.txt");

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("books.txt"));
     PrintWriter Pwr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter (tempFile));
     String line = null;

     //read from original, write to temporary and trim space, while title not found
     while((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
         if(line.trim().equals(title)){
             continue;          }
         else{
             Pwr.println(line);
             Pwr.flush();

         }
     }
     // close readers and writers
     br.close();
     Pwr.close();
     titlerem.close();

     // delete book file before renaming temp
     inputFile.delete();

     // rename temp file back to books.txt
     if(tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)){
            System.out.println("Update succesful");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Update failed");
        }
    }
}
```

the text file is called books.txt and contents simply should look like:

```
bookone author1 subject1
booktwo author2 subject2
bookthree author3 subject3
bookfour author4 subject4
```

thank you any help would be appreciated

Comment: Using the search function saves a great deal of time.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use

```
if(line.trim().startsWith(title))
```

instead of

```
if(line.trim().equals(title))
```

because [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is only true if both strings are equal, and [`startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) is true if `line.trim()` starts with `title` ;)

Comment: i did search and find that sample code Woot4Moo but that is a single string in a line which i have achieved. The spaces between strings were causing me the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you are reading the file line by line. You can make use of following

```
  if(line.contains(title)){
     // do something
  }
```

In this case you will not be limited by title only.

[String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: contains solved the problem. All the comments gave me a different direction to look in its difficult to get your head around as a learner. smit, JoshDm,jlordo thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MattBrookes I am glad it helped. jlordo suggested correctly by your implementation. However if you caught in any problem like this you can definitely look at ``Java API DOCs`. I included in my answer.

Comment: Based on which answer you ended up using, you should accept one so this question can be closed out.

Answer (score 0):

`br.readLine()` sets the value of variable `line` to "bookone author1 subject1".

`Scanner.next()` delimits by whitespace.  You need to consolidate all your calls to Scanner.next() to a single String before checking against the lines in the file, if that is your intent.

In your case, if you typed "bookone author1 subject1", value of variable `title` would be "bookone" after your call to `Scanner.next()`.

Comment: and I guess OP wants to remove the complete line, if the user enters _bookone_

Comment: I'll assume that's correct since the variable is named `title` and not `myEntireDataLine`.