# how to delete a particular lines from a text file in java

Tags: java

i need to delete or remove first 6 lines of this file(give below is my input file) and write the remaining in a seperate text file?how can i do that....

```
[S:00]
{org:en}
I called the number and the lady told me she was talking on the phone to Toby Studabaker,'' Sherry Studabaker told BBC television.

{/org}
{unl}
agt(call(icl>do,equ>dial,plt>thing,plf>thing,agt>volitional_thing,rec>thing).@entry.@past,i(icl>person):01)
and(:01,call(icl>do,equ>dial,plt>thing,plf>thing,agt>volitional_thing,rec>thing).@entry.@past)
rec(call(icl>do,equ>dial,plt>thing,plf>thing,agt>volitional_thing,rec>thing).@entry.@past,number(icl>abstract_thing,icl>quantity,obj>thing).@def)
agt:01(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):01.@entry.@past,lady(icl>woman>person).@def)
rec:01(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):01.@entry.@past,i(icl>person):02)
agt:02(talk(icl>communicate>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>thing,ptn>person).@entry.@past.@progress,she(icl>person))
cob:02(talk(icl>communicate>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>thing,ptn>person).@entry.@past.@progress,phone(icl>electronic_equipment>thing,equ>telephone).@def)
ptn:02(talk(icl>communicate>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>thing,ptn>person).@entry.@past.@progress,toby)
nam:02(toby,studabaker:01)
agt:03(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):02.@past,sherry(icl>fortified_wine>thing).@maiuscul)
nam:03(sherry(icl>fortified_wine>thing).@maiuscul,studabaker:02)
rec:03(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):02.@past,bbc(iof>organization))
obj:03(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):02.@past,television(icl>broadcasting>thing))
and(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):02.@past,:02)
obj:01(tell(icl>say>do,cob>uw,agt>person,obj>uw,rec>person):01.@entry.@past,:03)
{/unl}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove  and you need some tinkering work to achieve your need.

Answer (score 1):

How do you do that?

```
  open input file
  open output file
  repeat:
      read line
      is line number greater than 6?
         write line
  until EOF
  close files
```

Now code it in Java.

---

There is no clever way to do this in Java, and I'm not aware of any 3rd party libraries that would significantly simplify this (already very simple) problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended to be a "write code for free" service ... and I'm not willing to indulge you.

Comment: i am also not intersted to get code for free...i dont have idea to do this.....thats y i have asked for the step or pseudocode.i am working on the steps that was give in last post....