# Java FileUtils: remove specific line from file

Tags: java, fileutils

How can I delete a specific line (by index) from a text file with the class `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`?

The index of the line to be deleted already know him, so I need some method that I delete a specific line from a file.

Comment: Have you read: [Find a line in a file and remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove) ?

Comment: If you really wish to use the Apache FileUtils, you could use the `lineIterator(File)` method, add those lines to a `Collection<String>`, remove the `ith` line, then use the `writeLines(File, Collection<?>)` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lineIterator function of the same library.

- Get the Line Iterator of the file
- Iterate over the lineIterator and write it to the temporary file.
- Maintain the index of the current iteration. If in the above step, the line number matches the number you want to skip, dont write it to temporary file.
- Close both file (handle the case if you exceptions. you may want to use finally as well)
- delete old file.
- rename the temporary file to new file

fyi, Iterator loads lazily into memory and drops reference to previous line when next is called.
[@Obicere : Also, I can not comment directly to the question but loading all the lines to memory does not like a good idea. ]