# Removing a line from a txt file java

Tags: java, string

I have a large file in which I need to remove only a number of lines
Is there any way to do this without opening a new file and copy the whole text?

edit:
the main problem is when it runs in more then one thread with large txt filse the program fails

Comment: write a script to do so and invoke it with java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it

Comment: i know this option, im looking for a way to do so without coping the whole text (i know the line number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this without opening a new file and copy the whole text?

No there isn't.  Certainly, there isn't if you want to do it *safely*.

And `RandomAccessFile` won't really help you either.  It would allow you to replace a sequence of bytes in the file with an equal number of bytes, but that doesn't amount to deleting a line.

You could use a RAF like this:

> Given an initial state `L1L2L3...LN` replace `L2L3...LN` with `L3...LN`

or you could use the RAF to "slide" the lines one at a time as per @halfbit's answer.

However:

- In the worst case you are copying the entire file content, and the average case involves reading and writing the bytes of `O(N)` lines.
- The simple way of doing this requires holding `O(N)` lines in memory.
- The "sliding" approach requires `O(N)` I/O operations (i.e. system calls).
- **Most importantly:** line deletion by in-place file update is risky.  If the application is interrupted in the middle of the process (e.g. power failure), then you will end up with a corrupted file.

FWIW: this is not a limitation in Java *per se*.  Rather it is a limitation of the way that modern operating systems represent / model files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Random Access Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) so that you can position your file pointer on the desired location and move the text .

Answer (score 0):

Here is some standalone example code using `RandomAccessFile` to remove lines without *opening a new file*, which seems to work for me. (In-place copying is required though.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // prepare test file
        String path = "/tmp/test.txt";
        writeTestLines(path, 999999);

        // mode "rws": read + write synchronous
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rws");

        int bufSize = 1 << 20; // 1 MiB
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(raf.getFD()), bufSize));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(raf.getFD()), bufSize));
        long writeOffset = 0;
        for (int nr = 1;; nr++) {
            if (!s.hasNextLine())
                break;
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if (nr != 2 && !line.contains("00")) {
                // switch to writing: save read offset, seek write offset
                long readOffset = raf.getFilePointer();
                raf.seek(writeOffset);
                pw.println(line);
                // switch to reading: save write offset, seek read offset
                writeOffset = raf.getFilePointer();
                raf.seek(readOffset);
            }
        }

        // write buffered output and truncate file
        raf.seek(writeOffset);
        pw.flush();
        raf.setLength(raf.getFilePointer());

        pw.close();
        s.close();
        raf.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public static void writeTestLines(String path, int n) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(path);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) pw.println("line " + i);
    pw.close();
}
```

Note that this code assumes that line endings read by the Scanner are the same as produced by PrintWriter (e.g. not just a single LineFeed on Windows).

Note that above code could be optimized to not rewrite any unchanged file head - e.g. by just tracking the write offset first and then switching to a "normal" PrintWriter.