# How to remove a line in text file java?

Tags: java

Basically I have this code.. I want to be able to display the delete a line in the text file ..

Example:

```
Gab 223-2587
Mark 221-5678
Reca 227-7589
Feb 224-8597
```

Command:

```
remove Mark
```

The result in the text file should be:

```
Gab 223-2587
Reca 227-7589
Feb 224-8597
```

My problem is, it doesn't remove the line that I want to remove.. and the text file becomes empty.. Or if i add a contact and then attempt to remove an existing contact.. the file will only contain the recently added contact..

Here's my code:

```
  File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Gab Real/workspace/CSc121/MyContacts.txt");
    System.out.println(String.format("File.canWrite() says %s", inputFile.canWrite()));

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = "";
    String currentline = " ";
    StringBuilder fileOutput = new StringBuilder();

    while((currentline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        fileOutput.append(currentline + "\r\n");
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(inputFile);
    out.println(fileOutput.toString());


    if(word.startsWith("add")){
        out.append(entries[1] + " " + entries[2] + "\r\n");
        //out.println(out.toString());
        //out.write("\r\n");
    } 
//my if condition to remove a line
    else if (word.contains("remove")){
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if(trimmedLine.contains(entries[1])) continue;
                out.append(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not working? Please provide more information.

Comment: umm the `else if ` without any `if` before it looks VERY ODD

Comment: Why does removing `Mark` kill `Feb`, too?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it

Comment: @Ascalonian i've edited my post.. can u re-read it please? i badly need help right now :(

Answer (score 2):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(inputFile);
```

AAARGH. Please, *never* name an output file `inputFile`...

[image]

Also, don't hardcode DOS linewraps `"\r\n"`. This makes your program non-portable.

Other than that, your program logic is just completely busted...

You already read all lines in the **first**

```
while((currentline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Your second attempt at filtering the lines thus fails, because **you are already at the end of the file**, from your first read above.

Two solutions:

1. Don't read the file until you need to, or *reread* it every time.
2. Read it only *once* into a modifiable data structure, such as `LinkedList<String>`. Do all the modifications; then write it out in the end, once.

Comment: Actually, he's reading the file into memory and then writing into the same one.

Comment: @leonbloy which doesn't matter much, because he already finished reading it before he does open it for writing; and he probably didn't *lock* it anyway. The real problem is that he exhausted the contents already before coming to the second read.

Comment: there's no need to be harsh or something @Anony-Mousse.. i'm still a student and new to java.. :3

Comment: You ought to learn about this "fun" thing. It often involves kittens... and it's fun.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read and write the same file at the same time. Either read everything into memory first, before creating `PrintWriter` or write to a different file (and then, possibly, copy it over to the original after you are done).

Also, be sure to `.close()` your writer after you are done writing to it.

Oh, and, yes, you cannot read from the same reader twice. If you want to start reading from the beginning, create a new reader.

Comment: "Either read everything into memory first, " But that's what he's doing

Answer (score 0):

Your program conflates several concerns. Try to separate them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  String command = ...; // take it from args somehow
  String marker = ...; 
  ...
  if ('remove'.equals(command)) removeLine(marker);
  else if...
  ...
}

void removeLine(marker) {
  // open files as you already do
  while((currentline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     if (currentLine.indexOf(marker) < 0) {
       output.writeln(currentLine);
     } // else the line is skipped
  }
  // close files
}
```