# How to delete an object that are written into file?

Tags: java, list, file-io, arraylist, fileoutputstream

In my program, user gives some inputs and those are added into an arrayList. The arrayList object are written into file. Thus I have a created method for writing into and read from file (using file-i/o & object-i/o stream).

Now If I want to delete a particular object from the file, how do I do that?

This is the part of I am workin on:

```
case 4:
                bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();//method calling; BankAccount is the class for settre and getter

                Iterator<BankAccount> it=bankAccounts2.iterator();//bankAccounts2 is the arrayList for reading file

                System.out.println("Enter the account you want to delete:");
                deleteAcc = sc.nextInt();

                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    BankAccount next = it.next();
                    if (next.getAccNum() == deleteAcc) {
                        it.remove();
                    }
                }

                break;
```

Comment: Rewrite the file without the content?

Comment: "[How to] Find a line in a file and remove it" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution in my mind is to read all the objects from the file into an `ArrayList`. Then remove the one you want to delete from the aforementioned list. Finally, **overwrite** the initial contents of the file with the new contents in the list.

If you do not want to re-read the contents of the file and you have a reference to the list of objects in memory, then you can just remove the object and **overwrite** the contents of the file