# Delete existing row from CSV file and create new one in Jackson

Tags: java, csv, jackson-dataformat-csv

I am using `Jackson` to read and write to CSV file. I am writing a API which accepts a JSON request and write the `java object` into CSV file which is working fine, but I am not sure how to check in csv file that given data or `java object` is already present. I need to check that data is present so delete that entire row and add new data which coming from API.

e.g. I have below CSV file data -

```
id,name,gender,action
 1,abc,male,add
 2,def,male,delete
```

My Rest API is below to -

```
@PostMapping(path= "/config", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateConfig(@RequestBody List<EmpData> configs){
    File file = new File(CONFIG_FILE);
    Util.addOrUpdate(file, configs);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("SUCCESS");
}


 public static void addOrUpdate(File file, List<EmpData> data) {
    
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true);
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(EmpData.class)
            .withColumnSeparator(',');

    File outputFile = new File(file.toURI());
    try {
      
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(EmpData.class).with(schema);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile , true);
        writer.writeValues(os).writeAll(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine for adding new row in a csv file, but how can I delete existing row if present and add new one.

I want to compare with `id`, if given `id` in REST API body is present in csv file then delete it from csv and create new record with that `id` from REST API body.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like described here [Find a line in a file and remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it). If your csv always starts with id, you can easily filter it out.